# avoid reload gridview c# after clicking on a button

Tags: c#, gridview

I created a web page Default6.aspx containing a gridview.
This gridview contains w column "radio button" (just one radio button can be selected)
I have a button that when I click,the Id of the row checked will be shown.
The problem that after click on the button,the checked radio button becomes **unchecked** and the gridview loads new data.
I couldn't really understand why.
Note: I have the same code in another Default5.aspx and it works.

this is the code of gridview:

```
<div style ="height:250px; width:1092px; overflow:auto;" spellcheck="True">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
                  BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="4" GridLines="Vertical" Height="160px"  
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="271px" ForeColor="Black" 
                  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoPostBack="false">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns >
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Main" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton  ID ="radioButton1" HeaderText="Main" runat="server" 
                                      onclick = "RadioCheck(this);" AutoPostBack ="False" Checked="False" CausesValidation="True" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value = '<%#Eval("id")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#80FF00" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

and this is the code of the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#80FF00" Font-Size="Large" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Delete unselected rows" Width="200px" />
```

for the test I created another button that just shows me a message "hello" when I click on it..and when I did (even I don't check a radio button),the gridview became refreshed..

what can be that?
thank you

Comment: The button causes a Postback which in means the page is loaded again. See [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: I tried to add to the button:PostBack="false" but it didn't help..what should I do plz?

Comment: what should I do please.. :( I couldn't find the solution

Answer (score -1):

Consider wrapping your button and the label in an `updatepanel` control, which uses AJAX to refresh their contents. The rest of the page will not be reloaded and the action will not affect the browser navigation.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is:

if (!IsPostBack)
{ //my code}
else
{ //nothing to do}